# GWT clickHandler inside infoWindow marker

Tags: google-maps, gwt, infowindow

I tried make a click handler inside info window marker, but it doesn't work. Click event is never called. 
I've found some solutions for Google-Maps API with JAVASCRIPT, but in GWT i not found.

I tried a many modes to add click handler in a button, inside info window of a marker, no one works.

Someone can help me?

```
class Curtindo implements ClickHandler{

    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // EXAMPLE
        Window.alert("Test");
    }

}

Curtindo click = new Curtindo();

final Button but_curtiu = new Button("",click); 
but_curtiu.setHTML("<div style='float:left; margin-left:5px'><img src='monografia/images/like.png' alt='Curtir'/>Curtir</div>");

//obj_geo is a marker
obj_geo.addMarkerClickHandler(new MarkerClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(MarkerClickEvent event) {
        InfoWindow info = Monografia.map.getInfoWindow();
        info.open(obj_geo, new InfoWindowContent("" +
                "<b>Nome: </b>"+aux[1]+"<br/>"+
                "<b>Descrição: </b>"+aux[2]+"<br/>"+
                "<div id=\""+aux[0]+"\">"+but_curtiu+"</div>"+panel));           
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel htmlPanel=
    new com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLPanel(("" +
                "<b>Nome: </b>"+aux[1]+"<br/>"+
                "<b>Descrição: </b>"+aux[2]+"<br/>"+
                "<div id=\""+aux[0]+"\"></div>"+panel));

 htmlPanel.add(but_curtiu, aux[0]);
```

Comment: Tim, button appears inside InfoWindow, but do you know if its possible to capture events? Tried without success with button.addClickHandler and button.addDomHandler(handler , ClickEvent.getType()).